# Get order ID in custom module's email's subject

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates

I've a custom module which sends an **Pre-order confirmation email** to customer before order confirmation email sent to customer.

Once admin reviewed order then only **order confirmation** triggered.

I would like to include **Increment ID** in Pre-order confirmation email's subject.

I've tried something like,

`{{trans "SiteName Order #%order_id" order_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}`

But doesn't seems to work with custom module's email, Whereas it worked with order confirmation email.

Any idea how can I achieve this ?? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to get order id when sent pre order email..?
I think you can write code for "Pre-order confirmation email" after order create and before admin review code, i think you are sending pre order email before create a order, so it's not generate your incremented id .

Comment: Which observer do you use?

Comment: I've used `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya, No I'm not sending pre-order email before placing an order, I'm sending after order placed successfully

Comment: Try using `sales_order_save_after` observer.